# Create GIF using nodejs and sharp

Tags: node.js, gif, sharp

I am struggling to create a gif using the [sharp](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-output#gif) library in nodejs. I am able to successfully create the frame-images that I want to use for the gif, but am not able to use them to create a gif. I am not sure if sharp even supports what I want to do, as I am getting an error when passing the frames as an array, which I thought was the right way to do this?

```cs
//Convert frames to GIF animation
const image = sharp([imagel, image2] {
  animated: true,
})
  .gif(f{ loop: 0 })
  .toBuffer();
```

Error on executing `node`:

```
/usr/local/bin/node ./server.js
Server running on port 3000
Process exited with code 1
Uncaught Error Error: Unsupported input '?PNG

IHDR ?? e???   pHYS 0 0 Q[Rk 0IDATXO0Q3LOOqu@M.60B000000 EOO
OZLAJ Q00!@(AJ Q00 !@(AJ 000 !@(A J 000 !@CAJ 000 !@CA
```

Answer (score 1):

`Unsupported input '?PNG`

This could mean the PNG format is not a valid input for that [`gif` function](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-output#gif)

It can be used to convert other (already) animated images to an animated gif, but since PNG is not animated, you would get that error.

You might need to use instead [`gifencoder`](https://github.com/eugeneware/gifencoder) + `canvas` (`npm install gifencoder canvas`).
Something like:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Canvas = require('canvas');
const GIFEncoder = require('gifencoder');
const sharp = require('sharp');

// Define the output path for the GIF.
const outputPath = 'animated.gif';

// Define the input PNG files.
const inputFiles = ['image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png'];

// Create a GIFEncoder instance.
const encoder = new GIFEncoder(500, 500); // Change the dimensions as needed.

// Pipe the encoder output to a writable stream.
const output = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath);
encoder.pipe(output);

// Start encoding.
encoder.start();

// Loop through the input files.
inputFiles.forEach(async (file) => {
    // Convert each PNG to a raw RGBA buffer.
    const data = await sharp(file).raw().toBuffer();

    // Create a new Canvas instance.
    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(500, 500); // Change the dimensions as needed.
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Create an ImageData instance from the raw RGBA buffer.
    const imageData = new Canvas.ImageData(
        new Uint8ClampedArray(data),
        canvas.width,
        canvas.height
    );

    // Put the ImageData instance into the canvas.
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

    // Add the frame to the GIF.
    encoder.addFrame(ctx);
});

// Finish encoding.
encoder.finish();
```

That would read each PNG file, converts it to a raw RGBA buffer using sharp, puts the image data into a canvas, and then adds the canvas as a frame to the GIF using `gifencoder`.

Comment: Locally it works without problems but when I upload it to the online server the canvas module is full of errors

Comment: @PruteanuAlexandru Can you check the version of Node.js on your server by running node -v, and compare it with the version you are using locally?

Comment: @PruteanuAlexandru Also, when deploying a Node.js application, it is usually best to only upload your own code and the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files, and then run `npm install` on the server to install the dependencies. This ensures that the correct versions of the dependencies are installed for the server's environment.